# Constant visibility for constant object on filter at app.js

Tags: angularjs

At app.js I have a constant and a custom filter definition. The constant object must be used at the filter but I have an error 'statusInfo is not defined' when I try to reference the constant object at the filter.

Please where is my mistake ?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
myApp.constant('statusInfo', {
    status1: 1 ,
    status1: 2 ,
    status1: 3
})

myApp.filter('myCustomFilter', function () {
    console.log('Status ', statusInfo ) // Here I have the error.
    ...my code...
}
```

Comment: You don't need a constant. Just declare the object in a script loading before angular. You need a global JS variable. Therefore it's going to be accessible from any controller, directive or service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include statusInfo as a parameter to your filter, as follows:

`myApp.filter('myCustomFilter', function (statusInfo) {...`